# Alternative to wrld_simpl in R?

Tags: gis, distribution

I'm looking for something similar to wrld_simpl (which is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame built into the package maptools found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/maptools/man/wrld_simpl.html) but with more detail. It works great for large scale maps but here is the problem: [image]

When trying to map the northern coastline of Australia, the polygon is not accurate enough. Is there a similar object that I can use in R Studio that has better resolution than wrld_simpl?
Or is there a way to increase the resolution of wrld_simpl?

The way I loaded the object was with this function:

`data(wrld_simpl)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

What worked for me was to use `library(maps)` instead of `library(maptools)` and simply put in the line:

```
map("world2", add = TRUE)
```

instead of

```
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl,add=TRUE)
```

Hope it works the same for you!